# How to get facebook page's page_id via facebook connect?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebooktoolkit

I have a facebook connect site using the c# facebook toolkit.

I want to publish some stuff on the user's facebook page's wall. I can do this using the stream.publish in the Open Stream API. But, to do any of this a page_id is required. Yet, I don't see any methods where you can get access to the page_id based on the user_id.

So, basically; different users will use my web application. I want to allow them to publish content to the facebook pages that they "admin". But to do this, I must know the page_id first; which I don't know how to get. None of the other API methods were helpful.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by querying the [page_admin table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Page_admin_%28FQL%29) using FQL.

eg `select page_id from page_admin where uid = 123`

Here's the [intro page on the FQL api](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL), and here's the [full list of tables](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables) available for querying via FQL.